# Adding Regular Expression minimum & maximum string limit to "\n" in word boundaries validation

Tags: regex, validation, newline, minmax, exceed

If inputted text doesn't match with my pattern:

```
^(\b[\n]\w*\s*)+$
```

Which is if finding \n character in the inputted text then the text will not be validated, but I want to add min and max length to all whole string. I expect if the text doesn't match the pattern and string length lower than 3 and exceed 10 then it will not be validated, I know this following pattern is not correct but at least I'm trying to modify it like this:

```
^(\b[\n]\w{3,10}\s*)+$
```

For sample:

```
FrogFrog
FrogFrog <- it won't validated because has \n and exceed 10

Frog
Frog <- it won't validated because has \n

FrogFrogFrog <- it wont't validated because exceed than 10

FrogFrogFr <- it is valid because no \n character and not exceed than 10
```

Any correction or suggestions?

Comment: It looks as though all you need is `^.{3,10}$`. Or, if there can only be letters, digits, or `_`, `^\w{3,10}$`. Please share your code if it still does not work and you need help.

Answer (score 0):

try this regex :

```
^([\w\s]{3,10})(?!\n)$
```

Comment: i've try this pattern, result is char length limitation not affect to second line even first line is validated

Comment: `(?!\n)` mean if followed by \n text will not validate

Answer (score 0):

You might start the match with a word character to match at least a character at the start.

Then repeat 2-9 times matching either a word character, space or tab using a character class and end the pattern with `\z` to assert the end of the string.

```
^\w[\w \t]{2,9}\z
```

For example a [regex demo with  match](https://regex101.com/r/i2uHQ5/1) and a [regex demo with no match](https://regex101.com/r/CIqoAK/1).